# Why doesn't ccrewrite get called when I publish my project(s)?

Tags: build-process, visual-studio-2013, code-contracts, asp.net-web-api2

I finally have ccrewrite working, and my unit tests are passing, but when I publish a web project, it keeps blowing up as if it hadn't been rewritten.  After checking with JustDecompile, the code hasn't been rewritten:

```
 Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(log != null, "Must provide a valid ILog to UmbracoServiceProvider");
 Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(contentService != null, "Must provide a valid IContentService to UmbracoServiceProvider");
 Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(examineManager != null, "Must provide a valid ExamineManager to UmbracoServiceProvider");
```

The above should be `__ContractsRuntime`... if it had been rewritten.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When publishing, it was building the 'Release' configuration, which has it's own set of code-contract settings which I hadn't set up yet.